# Visual Studio Code PowerShell Terminal Ansi Characters

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

A few days ago Visual Studio Code Powershell terminal started displaying ansi characters in the path. This does not happen for bash or cmd terminal.

```
633;A633;P;Cwd=C\x3a\\Temp\\barry\\repo\\x2dcloud\x2dapplication\x2dpocsPS C:\Temp\barry\repo\cloud-application-pocs> 633;B
```

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking why this happens? Are you asking how to make it stop happening? Maybe you should read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

This is very wierd. Someone provided a link that answered this question a few hours ago. The info in the link fixed the problem. Then someone wrote a commit that the user need to provide a better answer. Then the user deleted the answer!

So I am putting the answer back.
setting `terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled` to false should fix this

for more info see: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/160419